# Basic excel date and time problem

Tags: excel, date, time, comparison

Have a list of dates in excel in the format (this comes originally from csv):

```
23/11/09 07:27:02
23/11/09 08:01:50
23/11/09 08:38:58
23/11/09 09:40:01
```

What I want to do is count the number of these falling between hour blocks, like 7-8, 8-9, 9-10 etc
Not sure how to get started, but one idea was just to put logic statements comparing the dates between these blocks, then adding the total "trues"

I can't get it to compare properly. When I type it the hour block marks,

```
    e.g. 23/11/09 08:00 
excel actually shows that as 
23/11/2009 8:00:00 AM
```

and the compare doesn't work. Well actually it does the opposite of what it should.

that is:

```
=IF(C5>L1,IF(C5<M1,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
```

C5 being date in top codeblock, L1 and M1 being the hour blocks I manually entered in the second code block.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=hour(a1)=7
```

will return true if the time of the date/time value in cell A1 is between 7 and 8 (AM) and will otherwise return false.

Comment: thanks heaps. did a number of googles on datetime but was heading in the wrong direction. Now can I perform something like =COUNTIF(K:K, this cell = 7), =COUNTIF(K:K, this cell = 8) etc ? experimenting now...

Comment: Got it, just remove this cell = so its =COUNTIF(K:K,8). 
Thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: Yeah, so say that you have date/time values in column A and you have the formula `=hour(A1)` in cell `B1`, `=hour(A2)` in cell `B2`, etc. Then you can say `=countif(B:B, "=7")` to count the number of date/time values with time between 7 AM and 8 AM.

Answer (score 1):

Excel stores dates as number of days since 1900 or 1904 depending on your setting and the time as a fraction of the days. So 11:59 am 4th of July 1960 is held internally as '22101.4993055556'.

As such you cannot do plain charactrer string comparisons on dates. However ther ar lots of nifty time/date functions available to you.

You probably want :

```
=IF(HOUR(B1) > 8,IF(HOUR(B1)<12,"YES","NO"),"NO")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Excel functions, like HOUR(), to extract the parts of the times, and apply the logic tests to those extracted values.